# In flutter how to use GetX to get and set first frame in video player?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-video-player

I am using [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) with GetX. And as you can see in official [example](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player#example), to get and set first frame of video as thumbnail, you have to use empty setState.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized,
        // even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

Now I am not able to understand even that how to figure out below code using GetX. (i.e. how do I get first frame using GetX and set it on video player as thumbnail.)

> // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized,
> // even before the play button has been pressed.
> setState(() {});

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I am using GetX hence I do not want to use stateful widget. So how can i achieve the same example using GetX, especially what this part is doing - setState(() {});

Answer (score 0):

actually the comment is pretty clear

> Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized,
> even before the play button has been pressed.

the purpose of the empty `setState` executed after video initialize is to **rebuild** ui once. so first frame of your video shown in the ui.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear... let me rephrase it -  I am using GetX hence I do not want to use stateful widget. So how can i achieve the same example using GetX, especially what this part is doing - `setState(() {});`

Comment: maybe you can create a bool somewhere, after initialization of vid you can set bool to true, so the ui will be rebuilt. tbh I prefer bloc or provider/riverpod because get X is redundant for state management, managed by one person, but has so many features.  this is just my opinion, everyone else have difference but you can check this post for your reference. https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/q95l2x/why_is_getx_hated/